# Android вывод приложений имеющих доступ к группе разрешений

Tags: android, permissions

Необходимо вывести какие приложения имеют доступ к определенной группе разрешений, а так же "включено" или "отключен" доступ к группе.

Подскажите, как примерно реализовать след. вид приложения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте тут посмотреть: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14672557/3212712